# Changing font of text inside an extension library dialog box?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How do you change the text within the extension library dialog box?   No matter what I do, the text remains the same size.   I can see the font change in the designer cleint but not in the browser.   I tried looking at it with IE Developer Tools but I can't even see the text anywhere.

Comment: Are you trying to change standard text or fields?

Comment: Without further details it's hard to guess what you're trying to achieve; I built a standard extlib dialog with some fixed text, tried it with Firefox and MSIE.: no problem whatsoever changing font-size, -family, or -color. So if you're having trouble here it must be something specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what was going on yesterday but it just wasn't working.  I was simply trying to set the text size of a computed field inside a dialog box. I changed the font size in the properties of the computed field and seems to work now,  We have seen these issues on our dev server before.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change the text with text options but you can if you use HTML, and it should also work with CSS.

Standard `<h1><h2><h... oh you get the idea works for me.`